# AWS Network Load Balancer - TCP target group unhealthy threshold

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, health-monitoring

I have a question about health check configuration for a target group behind a network load balancer.

When I try to put different healthy/unhealthy thresholds I cannot change the unhealthy threshold and the infobox for this field specifies that must be the same than healthy threshold, but I'm not able to find any reason for this limitation.

Why is not possible to **set different healthy / unhealthy thresholds**?

I've seen a strange behaviour in autoscaling activities where all instances behind the target group were declared as unhealthy at the same time including one that have been added recently, taking the system out of service for a few minutes until scaling activity solve the problem.

Thanks in advance,